# How change line colours of the line series chart in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to change line colours of the line chart in flex.I want to pass colour array to line chart and have those colours in lines in line chart.This is my colour array

```
            private var colorArr:Array = new Array(
            new SolidColor(0x007C9C),   //default
            new SolidColor(0x019FCC),   //default 
            new SolidColor(0x8FCD3E),   //default 
            new SolidColor(0x82B93A),   //default
            new SolidColor(0x638A2D),   //default 
            new SolidColor(0xE3AAD6)    //default 
        );
```

I used this method to change colour.

```
                    var s:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
                s.setStyle("fill",colorArr);
```

but colours i defines inside array not apply to lines of line chart in flex.lines have flex default colours.
Guys do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for setting the line series color

```
var s:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
s.setStyle("lineStroke", new Stroke(0xFF0000, 2, 0.4));
```

Comment: yes this method is correct.but my requirement is to pass array of colours.

Comment: Do you want array of color for the single line seriers?

Comment: @ Sumit yes im trying to pass array of colours.